# SQL Server Select query doesn´t do anything

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to run a `Select` query with an ID entered in a textbox. And then showing the result on a label. But I have this code and when I hit the button, it doesn't do anything. Please help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-JO0MC7T\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True;User ID=****;Password=***");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select nombre from Prueba where Id=@zip", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", txtdataBase.Text);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            lbResultado.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger to see what's going on? Maybe your query isn't returning any rows.

Comment: what are you entering into that textbox?

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms? If it's webforms, are you changing the text of `lbResultado` at all during postback?

Comment: As a sanity check, also verify that the query returns rows INDEPENDENTLY OF YOUR PROGRAM by using SQL Server Management Studio (it's free) or some other query tool. Copy and paste your "Select nombre from Prueba where Id=" along with an ID value (surrounded by single quotes) into a new query window open on your database and execute it.  For example, Select nombre from Prueba where Id='12345'.   If you've written a poorly formed query, no amount of coding is going to fix your problem.

Comment: What data type is `id` in the database? And what's in `txtdataBase.Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated your solution in ASP.NET (code behind is similar if you're on WinForms). The code behind worked as you provided, so it could be that your query isn't returning results from your database or the click event isn't bind to the code behind:

**SqlExample.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SqlExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="SqlExample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblResultado" runat="server" Text="?"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbZip" runat="server" placeholder="zip"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**SqlExample.cs (code behind)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class SqlExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionData");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT nombre FROM Prueba WHERE Id=@zip", conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", this.tbZip.Text);

        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                this.lblResultado.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

**Sample data and results:**

[image: WebApp]

[image: Data]

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way maybe not much difference ===>assuming in your database when you run the query is returns data as you expect.

```
Using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-JO0MC7T\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True;User ID=****;Password=***"))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select nombre from Prueba where Id=@zip", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", txtdataBase.Text);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string myresult = reader.GetString(0);// what ever datatype
            lbResultado.Text = myresult; 
        }
    }
}
```